# In standardized regression with same number of samples, can one X variable have higher beta but lower T-stat than another

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error

Lets say I have $n$ observations of $Y$, $X_1$, and $X_2$. All three are normalized (mean 0, variance 1). I run two regressions:

1. $Y=\beta_1X_1$
2. $Y=\beta_2X_2$

Given these $n$ observations, is it possible for $\beta_1 > \beta_2$, but $tstat(\beta_1) < tstat(\beta_2)$ or for $\beta_1 < \beta_2$, but $tstat(\beta_1) > tstat(\beta_2)$?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for different signs, then yes.  If the standardized slopes (i.e., the correlations) have the same sign, then assuming you are using the same data set (and same sample size), no...it would not be possible for the t-ratios to go in the other direction.